# Using Custom Environment.ts Value for app relative paths in the CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have developed an angular2 app - without the cli and am now trying to move it inside the cli to take advantage of the built in testing and build processes.

The problem I have is that the app I've developed is going to be deployed inside a web content management system (ie DNN, drupal, joomla, etc...).  So the app cannot assume that it's files reside relative to the root of the website directory. (I currently solve this with systemjs by having two different config files)

For example, from the cli build the index.html file in the dist folder looks like this:

```
<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/DesktopModules/MyApp/dist/inline.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/DesktopModules/MyApp/dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/DesktopModules/MyApp/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

If I make these changes manually then the app works.  (I have only moved in the first / root component and anticipate some more issues moving forward.)

I am comfortable creating a gulp task to perform this but hope there is a way to have these differences handled by the angular-cli

### ONE IDEA:

If I add a custom environment file to the app/environment folder (environment.cms.ts) ie:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    envName: 'cms',
    dnnPath: '/DesktopModules/cms/'
};
```

Is there a way to use the **environment file** or **other setting/option** to tell the cli that when I use the ***ng build --prod --env=cms*** to add the path I show above in the second index.html file script paths.

Thanks in advance

JK

---

**PS:** I am not sure if this is the best place for this.  I did not feel that this was a bug and so did not want to create an issue in the github repository.  Is there another way people are discussing these types of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

If i just ready the documentation more closely i would have found my answer 
see this [link to the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml)

It states:

> **Base tag handling in index.html**
>
> When building you can modify base tag () in your
>   index.html with --base-href your-url option.
>
> Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html

```
ng build --base-href /myUrl/ 
ng build --bh /myUrl/
```